# How to remove Duplicates from two List except few elements which may be duplicate also?

Tags: c#

i have two lists having few elements in common, i want to remove duplicates events except few as described below..and the order of the string must be same and both list may not contain same no of elements?

```
  list A:                        List B
  ASCB                           ASCB
  test1                          test1
  test2                          test5
  test3                          test3
  test4                          test6
  Arinc                          Arinc
  testA                          testC
  testB                          testB
  testC
  tesctD
```

now i want to remove all common elements in two list except elements ASCB, ARINC.. how to do that can any one help me in that...

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the lists and looking at each item?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper  ya i tried but if any C# inbuilt function or by using LINQ ,will be more good

Comment: So are the exceptions in another list?

Comment: Can you please include your expected output list for this example

Comment: And output should be two lists with dupe elements removed from each, or one single combined list with dupes removed?

Comment: How are you determining which items you don't want to remove? Are they static can they change?

Comment: Clarification needed.  So you want the members that are in both lists removed from both (except for mentioned exceptions)?

Comment: @JefferyKhan yes ..only few static exceptions rest duplicates must be removed.

Comment: expected output..
final LIST

ASCB
test2
test5
test4
ARINC
testA
testC

Comment: The result goes in 1 list?

Comment: @user7116  yes  final order must be same ...only duplicates should be removed...

Comment: Does the order of the given lists matter?

Comment: @AustinSalonen  yes order of the list must be same..

Comment: You should edit your question to include all of this extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to test performance as I suspect it's not the most efficient.

```
List<string> wordstoKeep = new List<string>() { "ASCB", "Arinc" };

foreach (string str in listB)
{
    int index = listA.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (index >= 0)
    {
       if (!wordstoKeep.Any(x => x.Equals(str, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
           listA.RemoveAt(index);
    }
    else
       listA.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: @Deadlock - You're welcome although I just noticed in the comments that the order matters. This will iterate ListA then ListB rather than going side to side. Is that okay?

Comment: Ok. I've updated the answer to use case-insensitive searching so that `Test1` matches `test1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would just store the special values ( ASCB, ARINC, ect ) in their own list so I can use `Except` to get the difference between the two sets. You can add the special values in afterwards.

```
List<string> except = ListA.Except(ListB).Concat(listB.Except(ListA)).Concat(SpecialValues).ToList();
```

You have to call except twice because first we get items in A that are not in B. Then we add items that are in B but not in A. Finally we add the special values (I'm assuming SpecialValues is a collection with the strings you don't want removed).

Comment: `IEnumerable` has no `AddRange` method.  You need to use `Concat`.

Comment: I thought this would work at first but it assumes that `SpecialValues` are actually included all the time.

Comment: @keyboardP the OP said the `SpecialValues` would be static. If that's not the case he'd have to make some adjustments.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - I didn't downvote or anything as that aspect wasn't clear and this answer is fine. But I wasn't sure if OP said it as static as it may just be an example of words to not remove if they're in the list.

Comment: @keyboardP yeah, it's a limitation that should be pointed out. I could update with a solution that works no matter what but an answer has been accepted so it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - It's fine, I wouldn't update as your case could be the right one. Not enough details to go on.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listA = new List<string>{"ASCB","test1","test2"};
var listB = new List<string>{"ASCB","test1","test2"};
var combinedList = listA.Where(a => a.Contains("test"))
                        .Concat(listB.Where(b => b.Contains("test")))
                        .Distinct().Dump();
```

outputs 'test1', 'test2'

your filter conditions are contained in your `Where` clause.
`Where` can be whatever condition you want to filter by:
`Where(a => a != "ASCB"` or whatever...

`Concat` joins the two lists. Then call `Distinct()` to get unique entries.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var listA = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "ASCB",
                            "test1", 
                            "test2",
                            "test3",
                            "test4",
                            "Arinc",
                            "testA",
                            "testB"
                        };

var listB = new List<string>()
                        {
                            "ASCB",
                            "test1", 
                            "test5",
                            "test3",
                            "test6",
                            "Arinc",
                            "testC",
                            "testB"
                        };
var dontRemoveThese = new List<string>(){"ASCB", "Arinc"};
var listToRemove = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in listA)
    if (listB.Contains(str))
        listToRemove.Add(str);

foreach (var str in listToRemove){
    if (dontRemoveThese.contains(str))
        continue;
    listA.Remove(str);
    listB.Remove(str);
}
```

I like this solution because you can see what happens. I'd rather have 10 lines of code where it's obvious what happens than 1-3 lines of obscure magic.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the requirement that order must be the same

```
if(B.Count != A.Count)
    return;

List<String> reserved = new List<string>{ "ARCB", "ARINC" };

 for (int i = A.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
     if (!reserved.Contains(A[i].ToUpper()) && A[i] == B[i])
     {
         A.RemoveAt(i);
         B.RemoveAt(i);
     }
 }
```